# How is this summation an equation for a straight line?

Tags: statistics

In my class we are currently going over the support vector machine model, and in the lecture my professor says that the equation of the line in the graph below is the following:

$$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3 + . . . +a_0 = 0$$

[image]

As far as I can recall I have never seen an equation for a line like that. I tried to graph it on Desmos but was unsucessful. Can someone break down how that equation describes a line?

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it more, are each of those values one of the dots on the graph? If so I'm not sure how you can relate those dots to a line. Also, would those dots be only the ones in the center, around where you are potentially drawing a line to separate the two sections?

Comment: For two variables, this is a line. For example, 3x + 4y = 8 is equivalent to$ y = (-3/4)x+ 2$ if you prefer slope-intercept form.  For three variables, it is a plane, and for more variables it is called a hyperplane.

Comment: @matryoshka It seems that the method of linear regression has been applied.

Comment: @callculus42 I would have thought it was more likely to be an SVM separating hyperplane

Comment: @Henry That's possible as well. More context is necessary to know for sure what the graph represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are familiar with this form of a straight line (in 2D space): $y = mx + c$, where $m$ is the slope and $c$ is the intercept.

Consider rewriting this as $mx - y + c = 0$, or equivalently $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_0 = 0$, where $a_1 = m, a_2 = -1, a_0 = c$ and you can see the equivalence. This of course generalizes to higher dimensions.

You can start with other representations of a line you are familiar with and reduce it to the form you learned in your ML class.